# Обращение к неинициализированным полям класса/структуры с++

Tags: c++, ооп, классы, структуры

Есть структура:

```
struct MyS
{
    int ini = 256;
    int not_ini;
};
```

Теперь я вывожу поля этой структуры.

1 случай:

```
int main()
{
     MyS a;
     cout << a.ini << endl << a.not_ini;
}
```

2 случай:

```
MyS a;
int main()
{
     cout << a.ini << ',' << a.not_ini;
}
```

1 случай компилятор (msvc) даже не даст нам скомпилировать, т. к. он влечет за собой неопределенное поведение. А что начёт второго случая? Компилятор то скомпилирует его и на вывод мы получим `0`. Стоит ли так делать и является ли это безопасным с точки зрения стандарта?

Comment: Если писать `sruct`, то он оба раза не даст скомпилировать... А если `struct` - то без вопросов разрешает опять-таки оба варианта... VC++ 2019

Comment: Если значение не инициализированое, то неопределённое поведение. Нужно расчитывать что там может быть любое значение.

Comment: Если это глобальная область (случай 2) - то компиляторы чаще всего заполняют нулями, но не все, очередной компилятор может сделать не ноль (а запишет мусор из своего буфера например, мне так попадалось), и если это груповой код на гите - вам скажут что вы неправильно написали. Если вы пишите для себя - на свой страх и риск - вам не запрещено.

Comment: Если эту же структуру вы опубликуете в локальной области (случай 1) - там будет "стековый мусор". В ряде случаев там может попадаться значение которое ранее использовалось в вашей программе, но могут попадать и разные другие значения, и при смене ОС, или версии библиотек значения могут оказаться не такие как были раньше при тестировании. Это и называется неопределенное поведение.

Comment: @nick_n_a Если это глобальная область, то инициализация нулями гарантируется.

Comment: @nick_n_a, насчёт случая 2, в стандарте вроде бы написано, что неинициализированные переменные со статической продолжительностью хранения инициализируются нулем, относится ли это к экземплярам структур|классов?

Comment: @user7860670 гарантируется чем? Стандартом? Я встречал мусор в неинициализированых глобальных переменных. Не помню какой компилятор.

Comment: @nick_n_a Да, все глобальные переменные инициализируются нулем еще до стадии опциональной динамической инициализации. [basic.start.static]

Comment: @nick_n_a, в [basic.start.static] ничего не указано про классы, применимо ли вышесказанное вами для объектов классов?

Comment: Первый случай: ========== Сборка: успешно: 1, с ошибками: 0, без изменений: 0, пропущено: 0 ==========

Comment: `в стандарте вроде бы написано, что неинициализированные переменные со статической продолжительностью хранения инициализируются нулем, относится ли это к экземплярам структур|классов?` Да, относится. В стандарте используется конкретный термин — _zero-initialize_, и он имеет вполне конкретное описание. См.: [dcl.init.general/6](http://eel.is/c++draft/dcl.init.general#6). При нулевой инициализации объекта классового типа, все биты заполнения (если таковые имеются) устанавливаются в ноль, а затем члены-данные объекта также подвергаются нулевой инициализации.